# foreach using numlist of numbers with leading 0s

Tags: loops, for-loop, stata

In Stata, I am trying to use a `foreach` loop where I am looping over numbers from, say, `05`-`11`.  The problem is that I wish to keep the `0` as part of the value.  I need to do this because the `0` appears in variable names.  For example, I may have variables named `Y2005`, `Y2006`, `Var05`,  `Var06`, etc.  Here is an example of the code that I tried:

```
foreach year of numlist 05/09 {
   ...do stuff with Y20`year` or with Var`year`
}
```

This gives me an error that e.g. `Y205` is not found.  (I think that what is happening is that it is treating `05` as `5`.)

Also note that I can't add a `0` in at the end of e.g. `Y20` to get `Y200` because of the `10` and `11` values.

Is there a work-around or an obvious thing I am not doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another work-around is

```
forval y = 5/11 { 
     local Y : di %02.0f `y' 
     <code using local Y, which must be treated as a string> 
}
```

The middle line could be based on

```
 `: di %02.0f `y''
```

so that using another macro can be avoided, but at the cost of making the code more cryptic.

Here I've exploited the extra fact that `foreach` over such a simple numlist is replaceable with `forvalues`.

The main trick here is documented [here](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0051). This trick avoids the very slight awkwardness of treating `5/9` differently from `10/11`.

Note. To understand what is going on, it often helps to use `display` interactively on very simple examples. The detail here is that Stata is happily indifferent to leading zeros when presented with numbers. Usually this is immaterial to you, or indeed a feature as when you appreciate that Stata does not insist on a leading zero for numbers less than 1.

```
. di 05
5

. di 0.3
.3

. di .3
.3
```

Here we really need the leading zero, and the art is to see that the problem is one of string manipulation, the strings such as `"08"` just happening to contain numeric characters. Agreed that this is obvious only when understood.

Answer (score 3):

There's probably a better solution but here's how this one goes:

```
clear
set more off

*----- example data -----

input ///
var2008 var2009 var2010 var2011 var2012
0 1 2 3 4
end

*----- what you want -----

numlist "10(1)12"
local nums 08 09 `r(numlist)'

foreach x of local nums {
    display var20`x'
}
```

The `01...09` you can insert manually. The rest you build with `numlist`. Put all that in a `local`, and finally use it in the loop.

As you say, the problem with your code is that Stata will read `5` when given `05`, if you've told it is a number (which you do using `numlist` in the loop).

Answer (score 3):

Another solution would be to use an `if` command to count the number of characters in the looping value, and then if needed you can add a leading zero by reassigning the local.

```
clear    
input var2008 var2009 var2010 var2011 var2012
0 1 2 3 4
end

foreach year of numlist 08/12{
    if length("`year'") == 1 local year 0`year'
    di var20`year'
}
```

Comment: Good solution. Small abbreviations possible include  `if length("\`year'") == 1`.

Comment: Thanks, @Nick. I'll edit my answer with that. Probably slightly easier to read that way, too.

Comment: The one assignment `=` is also dispensable. Indeed `local year 0\`year'` will work.

Comment: Nice. I'll make that adjustment, too. @Nick